# error: expected ',' or ';' before 'FILE' in C Programming

Tags: c

I started writing C code, in a file called **example.c**, which was as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int intType;   
    float floatType;
    double doubleType;
    char charType;

    printf("size of int: %zu bytes\n", sizeof(intType));   
    printf("Size of float: %zu bytes\n", sizeof(floatType));    
    printf("Size of double: %zu bytes\n", sizeof(doubleType));    
    printf("Size of char: %zu byte\n", sizeof(charType));    

    return 0;    
}
```

and this program was written on VSCode and executed by code runner. After that I got this error:

```
[Running] cd "e:\c language\" && gcc example.c -o example && "e:\c language\"example

In file included from example.c:1:   
c:\users\deepak\mingw\include\stdio.h:260:34: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'FILE'    
  260 | _CRTIMP __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  FILE * fopen (const char *, const char *);   
      |
                                  ^~~~
In file included from example.c:1:   
c:\users\deepak\mingw\include\stdio.h:1131:13: error: expected ';' before 'int'   
 1131 | _END_C_DECLS    
      |             ^   
      |             ;  

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.402 seconds
```

I am new to programming so please help me. what should I do now?

Comment: Looks like you have messed up with your standard headers, or you compiler installation is broken

Comment: Or you didn't save the file before compiling, compiled the wrong file or something like that.

Comment: delete all versions of the compiler and associated files from your system, and reinstall it . Probably you have two different installations that are conflicting

Comment: @M.M you were right i had 2 compilers and forgot to set the system variables kinda messed up with that ,  thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your code works with no problem. I think problem is about your compiler. I use Devc ++.

Comment: And also try it with %d instead of %zu.

Comment: It's a good data point but is not really an answer as it does not give a solution to the problem. More appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for showing text.

Comment: @AbdulkadirArslan `"%zu"` is the correct format specifier for `size_t` which is generated by `sizeof`. Do not use `"%d"` for `size_t`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Not sure why this comment was added, but IIRC mingw compiler might be not supporting `%zu`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `"%zu"` is standard C since over 20 years. GCC supports it since a very long time, mingw uses GCC. You may talk about C++?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Take a look: https://pastebin.com/MuZcsN9H

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: **gcc** is just the compiler. `%zu` is a feature of the C library's `printf()` implementation. The GNU libc has had full support for `%zu` and other C99 features for a a very long time indeed, but MinGW does not use the GNU libc. It uses the C library provided by Microsoft for its legacy systems. Hence the lack of support for C99, which Microsoft spurned after trying to undermine it in a classic [EEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish) approach, leaving just Annex K as an optional extension.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123  i will try to be more cautious about my further comments and answers. I pay attention to your warnings. I am just a new contributer who wants to help and don't know much about the rules :D

Comment: same for @kaylum

Comment: No worries. FYI the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) pages have a whole section on how to answer questions and what makes good (and bad) answers.

Comment: @chqrlie yeah you were right, i deleted the mingw compiler and installed gnu which worked pretty good in my ide and the problem is solved . thank you so much for your help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my output when I ran it in my IDE:

```
size of int: 4 bytes

Size of float: 4 bytes

Size of double: 8 bytes

Size of char: 1 byte
```

---

The code itself works as intended; however, it seems like there was an error when you ran it in your environment.

The fact that it highlighted line 260 and 1131 made it seems like it ran the wrong file or a potential pipelining error. Try changing the name of your project and try again.

Comment: You may notice hat the line numbers are for file `stdio.h` included in line 1 of `example.c`, not for `example.c` itself. Besides that you don't provide a solution for the problem. Therefore this should rather be a comment than an answer.